# Is there any way to resolve domain to another domain with port?

Tags: domain, cname

we know we can use CNAME to implement:
access domain then resolve to a special domain like below:

```
domain1.com -> demo.com 
domain2.com -> demo.com
domain3.com -> demo.com
```

but is there any way to implement resolve to a domain with port?

```
domain1.com -> demo.com:3201 
domain2.com -> demo.com:3202
domain3.com -> demo.com:3203
```

---

EDIT:

I know use 302 can redirect to the special URL, but the domain in browser will change. is there any better way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you ask is to use a reverse proxy to hide the “origin” server.

Essentially, you have a server listening on domain1.com and it forwards the traffic to demo.com:3201.

DNS cannot do what you ask.